# What's the possible reason of selenium missing cookie of 'JSESSIONID'?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I'm testing an Active-X embeded web page with selenium 2 IE driver, but it seems `driver.get_cookies()` won't return `JSESSIONID` part, is there a reason why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEDriver has a bad history of messing up cookies information. Not directly related to `JESSIONID` but in my case it was not returning correct domain/expiry info etc. See an open [bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/391). Try chrome or firefox instead.